# Javascript onClick doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, html

I created a button code. See below:

```
<input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Login" onclick="tmpl_login_frm();" href="javascript:void(0);" data-reveal-id="tmpl_reg_login_container">
```

When I click on the button the button is not working and it doesn't execute the javascript. Can you please help me fix it?

I would like to show this button anywhere at post or page.

Comment: That's what `void(0)` does? Remove the href part, inputs don't have hrefs

Comment: `href` is a property of anchor not input

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I would strongly suggest that you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works and what we expect from a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine. I added below javascript and it worked as expected. Please try adding this to your code and see if it works -

```
<input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Login" onclick="tmpl_login_frm();" href="javascript:void(0);" data-reveal-id="tmpl_reg_login_container">

<script>
    function tmpl_login_frm() {
        console.log('vivek');
    }
</script>
```

But yes you should not use href with inputs as this is an invalid HTML.

Comment: Can you please show an example of full button code?

Comment: Why in your code showing console.log('vivek'). vivek is may be your name. Can you please tell more about it?

Comment: Yeah its my name. I have used it as a random string. :) You  can write any piece of code there and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it is working. Please check. Ref: https://jsfiddle.net/hcumg4bq/1/

```
<input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Login" onclick="tmpl_login_frm();" data-reveal-id="tmpl_reg_login_container">
    <script>
        function tmpl_login_frm() {
            window.alert("I'm clicked");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, If I click the button I  just would like to go to the <code>tmpl_login_frm()</code>. At my theme there is a similar built in button. That button is working. If I click that button then a simple login pop up opening. But at our code it is not opening the pop up login.

Comment: May you got the issue. If yes, can you please further test and fix it? Why the login pop up is not opening at our code?

Comment: I feel this is theme specific issue. Not javascript issue. Please check all the theme related imports and correct the tags and change your question with more theme specific details

Comment: My goal is to create a same link type button with pop up login feature. Does it make sense? Please

Comment: Waiting for your reply. Please share your ideas.

Comment: Hello, any suggestion? Waiting for your reply.

Comment: I tried adding <a data-reveal-id="tmpl_reg_login_container" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="tmpl_login_frm();">Login</a> in the <aside id="sidebar-contact_page_sidebar" class="sidebar large-3 small-12 columns"> tag and it worked for me. My best suggestion will be to check the internal mechanism of your theme and check if something is blocking your code.

Comment: I edited your website code in 'Inspect Element' of chrome for checking.

Comment: Awesome. It is working. But I want the functionality into a button. It is possible?

Comment: I think the classes you are using are tag specific, so it might not work with buttons. 

But we have a workaround, you can give button like styles to your this <a> tag, If you are using bootstrap then it is as simple as adding a "btn" class to your <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Login" onclick="tmpl_login_frm();" href="javascript:void(0);" data-reveal-id="tmpl_reg_login_container">
<script>
    function tmpl_login_frm() {
       alert("tmpl_login_frm");
    }
</script>
```

this code is work for me

Answer (score 0):

> your Code worked fine for me...
>   maybe it's because your navigator doesn't allow alerts !!

Open Chrome.
In the upper right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu ☰
Click Settings > Show advanced settings.
In the "Privacy" section, click Content settings.
In the dialog that appears, go to "Notifications" and choose the following:
Allow all sites to show notifications: You’ll automatically see notifications from all websites.

```html
<input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Login" onclick="tmpl_login_frm();" data-reveal-id="tmpl_reg_login_container">
    <script>
        function tmpl_login_frm() {
            window.alert("I'm clicked");
        }
    </script>
```